# Cron not running Python script if script not in home folder

Tags: python, linux, cron

I know cron is capricious and I am trying to figure out how to deal with it on linux.

I have the following `test_cron.py` executable Python script for testing cron :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

os.makedirs('test_cron_dir')
f = open('test_cron_dir/test_file','w')
f.write('stuff')
f.close()
```

I added two lines to my crontab to run the script in two different folders :

```
* * * * * python /home/me/test_cron.py
* * * * * python /home/me/some_folder/test_cron.py
```

The problem is : cron runs the `test_cron.py` script located in `/home/me/` but does not run the one located in `/home/me/some_folder/`.
I have changed the paths in the script to absolute paths but it does not change anything to the situation. Also, I have tried to use the root crontab and it does not change anything.

Can anyone please shine the light of knowledge and experience on me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked if /var/log/syslog (or other logs, depends on distro) provides any hints?

Comment: Your script is using relative directories and file paths in `os.makedirs('test_cron_dir')` and `open('test_cron_dir/test_file','w')`

Comment: Logs shows : `Aug  8 15:00:01 Computer CRON[1111]: (me) CMD (python /home/me/some_folder/test_cron_2.py)`
But I can't see the directory or files being created.

Unfortunately changing paths to absolute paths doe not change anything as I mentionned and the script runs without absolute paths when located in my home folder.

Comment: Correction ! For a reason I don't understand, absolute paths make the script work out of home directory.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is running [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) entries from the home directory of the user.

You need to change appropriately the directory i.e. to call the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall (either thru the `cd` shell builtin, or inside your python script using [os.chdir](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm)).

You should query the current directory (using [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), or the `pwd` command, or the [os.getcwd](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm) in Python) in your script.

Also check your `PATH` if running commands.

Comment: Thank you, I went through my whole real program and figured out it was actually a problem of absolute paths.

Comment: Example: "00 09 * * 3 cd /path/to/your/script; python yourScript.py"